# Javascript - Printing objects and (it shouldn't be printed) a function

Tags: javascript

I wrote a method from a book to sort elements by property however, in conjunction with another methods, I'm printing the objects inside an array and a function that I don't want to be printed, i.e., I don't want to print **By**.

**Output:**

```
first - Ursula
second - Arsulu
first - Vasti
second - Vista
first - Xena
second - Xane
first - Yoh
second - Yho
first - Zoe  
second - Zeo
By
```

```
// Method by takes a member name string and returns
// a comparison function that can be used to sort an
// array of objects that contain that member.
Array.by = Array.by || function (name) {
  return function (o, p) {
  var a, b;
  if (typeof o === 'object' && typeof p === 'object' && o && p) {
      a = o[name];
      b = p[name];
    if (a === b) {
      return 0;
    }
    if(typeof a === typeof b) {  
      return a < b ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return typeof a < typeof b ? -1 : 1;
  } else {
    throw {
      name: 'Error',
      message: 'Expected an object when sorting by ' + name
    };
  }
 };
};

  // traverse each object of the object passed as parameter
  Object.iterate = Object.iterate || function(o)
  {
             'use strict';
         var key, item; 
             for(key in o)
             {
                if(o.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
                {    
                   item = o[key];
                   if(typeof item === "object")
                   {
                      Object.iterate(item); 
                   }    
                   else {
                      document.writeln(key + " - " + item + "<br>");  
                   }
                }    
              }
         };

    <script type="text/javascript" src="arrayLib.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="objLib.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       // <![CDATA[

             var a = 
             [
                  {first: 'Zoe',  second: 'Zeo'}, 
                  {first: 'Yoh',  second: 'Yho'}, 
                  {first: 'Xena', second: 'Xane'},
                  {first: 'Vasti', second: 'Vista'}, 
                  {first: 'Ursula', second: 'Arsulu'}
             ];
               a.sort(Array.by('first'));
               for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
               {                        
                    Object.iterate(a[i]);
               }    
            // ]]>
      </script>
```

Comment: What is the ouput you're getting? What specific problem are you having — just that it's printing the function?

Comment: Yes, my only problem is that it's printing the function and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Try `if (!(Array.prototype.by)) { Array.by = ....; }`

Comment: @PhoenixWings The `By` doesn't appear with just the code you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/4cKb9/. Is there also an `Array.prototype.By` or `Object.prototype.By` (note: capitalized) being defined elsewhere?

Comment: When I run your code, it doesn't print 'By'

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski actually, no.

Comment: Also, I get  only 'By' if I remove the entire for block, but as you can see, the method by (and sort) even doesn't print anything. I'm really puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem was a

```
 <div>By</div>
```